# pyspark cannot print inside foreachbatch

Tags: pyspark, cassandra, spark-streaming

i have a simply python script to read streaming data from kafka and write to cassandra, code showed as below:

```
def saveToDB(batch_df, batch_id):
  print("inside foreachBatch for batch_id:{0}, rows in passed dataframe: {1}".format(batch_id, batch_df.count()))
  dfCollect = batch_df.collect()
  dfCollect.display(5, False)
#   print(dfCollect)
#   batch_df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
#           .option("keyspace", keyspaceName)\
#           .option("table", tableName)\
#           .mode("append")\
#           .save() 

  
df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("subscribe", TOPIC) \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_BROKER) \
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
    ....
    .load() \
    .select("account_id", "type", "time")


df_filtered = df.filter(df.account_id.isNotNull())
# df.display(5, False)


df_transformed = df_filtered.withColumnRenamed("accountId", "account_id") \
                     .withColumn("last_updated_dt" , lit(datetime.datetime.now())) 
#   df_transformed.display(5, False)

query = df_transformed.writeStream \
        .outputMode("append") \
        .option("checkpointLocation", "/myLocation") \
        .trigger(once=True)\
        .foreachBatch(saveToDB) \
        .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

the code ran fine, but it won't print anything inside the saveToDB() function. why? and how can i fix it?

Comment: Have you checked stdout on executors?